# Test Facebook live on Test App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am following below tutorial to publish live video on FaceBook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/getting-started#creating

From documentation what i have understood, that Facebook provides an stream URL, so that user can publish their content to that URL.

I have created a test app for this, now whenever I try to make a POST request to the live_videos edge, it throws an error saying:

**“(#200) App does not have permission to create live video on this user”.**

Please let me know any workaround on this.

Comment: Posting a live video requires `publish_actions` permission - which you currently can’t get. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#live-api-4-24

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the response, I was just wondering, is there a way to get `publish_actions`  permission for test APP.